# Login issue in my app

Tags: android

I have app and website. On app I have developed login functionality which take me to website pages after login.

But suddenly my login stopped working on app.  When I try to login with browser I do not face any issues. In app it gives message invalid credentials. I tried entering password manually many time but it fails. I tried other I'd s as well but it fails to logon in app but work on browser.

Then I tried installing app on another mobile phone and there I'd and password works fine. Tried uninstalling and installing app many time on the mobile where I started getting login issues but still do not work. Its really frustrating issue.

Answer (score -1):

Please check the configuration of phone which allows ur app to work normally and compare it with the phone which isn't working. A potential problem could exist the way in which the app is seeking permissions from the OS of the phone.

Comment: But it was working earlier with same app and started giving error now with same apk